# The difference btw Major and Chromatic Scale

Tags: theory, piano, chords, scales, learning

I learn music theory self study from Alfred book and I have a problem here 
As you see in question No 7 and 8 
I don’t know what do they mean by Major or chromatic scale

[image]

Thanks for you help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97061/discussion-between-phoog-and-tim).

Answer (score 4):

Any scale is merely a certain group of notes played in ascending/descending order.

The *major* scale is ubiquitous. Pieces using its notes (but not necessarily in that order!) are everywhere.

Simply put, the white keys on piano, starting and finishing on C, constitute the C major scale.

The spaces between the notes are in a certain pattern. T T S T T T S. As in C>D is a T(Tone), D>E is a T, E>F is a S(Semitone).

The *chromatic* scale is the one where every single note is played. Again, on piano, start on that C, but this time, play every single key - w,b,w,b,w,w etc. A rather different sounding scale. Alfred is getting you to differentiate between different sounding scales.